# Extracting band names of RasterLayer in R

Tags: raster, r, google-earth-engine, band

I have a RasterLayer with 500 bands in R (I exported the raster as a single image in Google Earth Engine, which was originally an ImageCollection).  I know you can extract the band you want to use by number:

```
raster("raster.tif", band = 1)
raster("raster.tif", band = 2)
# etc.
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to call the band by its name instead in R.

Comment: Are the band names even stored in the GeoTIFF? Does `gdalinfo("raster.tif")` using the `gdalUtils` package show them anywhere? If not, I think you are stuck unless you have a list of the names from somewhere else, otherwise you need to extract them from the `gdalinfo` metadata and lookup the band number to pass to `raster(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't help you with your currently downloaded file, but the ability to select by band name is included in the `rgee` package. https://csaybar.github.io/rgee/

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the package!